# Помогите с этой магией

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

https://outlets-pinko.ru/product/baby-love-bag-puff-maxi-quilt-black/ если листаешь вниз там галерея и при нажатии на любую фотку эта фотка появляется вместо основной на пк, и если с пк открыть мобильную версию тоже, а почему на мобилке не работает( движок WordPress помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Лично у меня на мобилке работает.

Comment: Открывал на Android. Браузеры - Chrome и Mi Browser